# Matplotlib has stopped working and gives a very long error... Any advice?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I had been trying to install numpy / scipy in different ways and to make sure I have lapack / blas support but somehow managed to mess things up so now when I do a simple plot it doesn't work and I need to type +c to interrupt and then get this lengthy error message. Any ideas for a fix? I've already installed and uninstalled python / numpy / scipy / matplotlib a couple of times but that didn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 536, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 363, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1093, in draw
    renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1042, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 754, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 320, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 214, in get_text_width_height_descent
    font = self._get_agg_font(prop)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 258, in _get_agg_font
    fname = findfont(prop)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1362, in findfont
    font = fontManager.findfont(prop, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1258, in findfont
    _rebuild()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1341, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1004, in __init__
    self.ttflist = createFontList(self.ttffiles)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 575, in createFontList
    font = ft2font.FT2Font(str(fpath))
KeyboardInterrupt

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1484, in __call__
    def __call__(self, *args):
KeyboardInterrupt

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
```

EDIT:

the code that raised the error was:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot(range(10))
# window doesn't show anything hangs, I end up typing <ctrl>+c and then the error appears
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that raised the said error?

Comment: yup added... though not sure how useful it is...

Comment: Install through Anaconda?

Comment: no.. through `apt-get` though tried to install through pip after having uninstalled it from `apt-get` as well but failed.

Comment: the main thing I've done was trying to get LAPACK / BLAS libraries sorted but I think I might have screwed things along the way. Also, at some point I had `ipython-notebook` installed but I've uninstalled that as well now.

Comment: Well the only thing that comes to my mind, that I'd do, is uninstall **everything** and then try again. If that doesn't work go for a new Ubuntu. But if `apt-get`, and `pip` don't work I honestly don't know. Might be worth trying Anaconda, it's always worked for me.

Comment: by everything do you mean a fresh install of Ubuntu?

Comment: The error it is reporting is KeyBoard interupt which means you `Ctr-c`'d the program.  It looks like it is re-building the font cache which can take a while.  Try being a bit more patient.

Comment: yup I definately ctrl-c 'd the program, it just seemed like it was taking forever. I'll have an instance run and let you know what happens